# Spring boot logout custom exception in SecurityContextLogoutHandler

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-security, spring-boot

i want to throw a custom exception on my Spring boot app when someone try to logout, what i need is to show to someone to do a step before make a logout, i try to override the logout method in a SecurityContextLogoutHandler, and redirect to an error page like this:

```
@Component
public class OnLogoutHandler extends SecurityContextLogoutHandler {

    @Autowired
    private JourneyTurnsServices journeyTurnServices;

    @Autowired
    private ClosingCashesServices closingCashesServices;

    public OnLogoutHandler() {

    }

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        try {
            JourneyTurn currentTurn = journeyTurnServices.checkActiveJourney();

            if (closingCashesServices.checkClosingCashRealized(currentTurn)) {
                super.logout(request, response, authentication);
                return;
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("/logoutUnclosedCashError");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This works but **i want to know if there is another way because i feel that i'm going out of the framework, i think that this is like a hack**.

Comment: *This works but i want to use Spring boot default error page throwing a custom exception.* **If** it works **what** are you asking?

Comment: because i feel it like a hack outside of the framework, and no like the exceptions in controllers where you use an @ExceptionHandler annotation, the idea of this post its for see if there is a better way than redirecting using HttpServletResponse, so delete it if you thing is useless